# Rails AJAX comments clear textarea

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, comments

I am adding AJAX comments on my web app, but I have no idea how to make textarea (where I wrote comment on) clear after adding comment. Additionally I am struggling to display errors when using AJAX.

My comment controller:

```
  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @guide = Guide.find(params[:guide_id])
    @comment = @guide.comments.build(comment_params)
    if @comment.valid?
      @comment.user = current_user
      @comment.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {
          flash[:notice] = "Comment added!"
          redirect_to :back
        }
        format.js
      end
    else
        flash[:danger] = "Comment must be 4 to 200 letters long"
        redirect_to :back
      end
    end
  end
```

JS file (create.js.erb):

```
$(".comments").html("<%= escape_javascript(render @guide.comments) %>);
```

View (guide/show.html.erb):

```
    ...
     <div class="add_comment">
        <%= form_for [@user, @guide, Comment.new], remote: true  do |f| %>
          <p>
            <%= f.text_area :body %>
          </p>
          <p><%= f.submit "Add comment" %></p>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class="comments">
        <%= render @guide.comments %>
      </div>
```

And my comment partial (_comment.html.erb):

```
<%= div_for comment do %>
  <div id="comment">
    <%= link_to image_tag(comment.user.avatar(:small)), comment.user %>
    <small><%= link_to " #{comment.user.username }", comment.user %> <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago.
    <% if comment.user == current_user || current_user.admin? %>
      <%= link_to "Delete", user_guide_comment_path(comment.user, comment.guide, comment), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>
    <% end %>
    </small>
    <br/>
    <span><%= comment.body %></span>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

To clearify - I want the area of adding new comment "AJAX TEST COMMENT" to clear itself after clicking submit and adding the comment and additionally any sugestions how to display error with AJAX would be appreciated.
[image]

EDIT: Yeah - the code does add new comment and renders all comments via ajax without refreshing the whole page.

```
Started POST "/users/1/guides/103/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-06 11:59:53 +0100
Processing by CommentsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "comment"=>{"body"=>"AJAX ANOTHER TEST COMMENT - IT IS WORKING"}, "commit"=>"Add comment", "user_id"=>"1", "guide_id"=>"103"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Guide Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "guides".* FROM "guides" WHERE "guides"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 103]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "comments" ("body", "guide_id", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["body", "AJAX ANOTHER TEST COMMENT - IT IS WORKING"], ["guide_id", 103], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2015-12-06 10:59:53.334245"], ["updated_at", "2015-12-06 10:59:53.334245"]]
   (42.3ms)  commit transaction
  Comment Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."guide_id" = ?  ORDER BY "comments"."created_at" DESC  [["guide_id", 103]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered comments/_comment.html.erb (13.8ms)
  Rendered comments/create.js.erb (15.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 65ms (Views: 17.1ms | ActiveRecord: 43.3ms)
```

Comment: Can You confirm that this is saving now, and also rendering all the `@guide.comments`?

Comment: Yup - It is saving the comment. Added logs to prove that. Additionally added the comment partial which I forgot to post there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor your `create` method in your controller as follow:

```
  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @guide = Guide.find(params[:guide_id])
    @comment = @guide.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user
    @comment.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {
        flash[:notice] = "Comment added!"
        redirect_to :back
      }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Here, the error is not being handled in the controller, we will go ahead to do this in the `create.js.erb` file, and display the flash as follow:

```
$(".comments").html("<%= escape_javascript(render @guide.comments) %>");
$('#comment_body').val('');
<% if @comment.errors.empty? %>
  $("#notice").html("Comment was successfully posted.");
<% else %>
  $("#notice").html("Error! Comment not posted.");
<% end %>
```

This is assuming that you have the `#notice` div on the page - (this is usually present on every rails app page, since it comes from `application.html.erb`

This same approach can be used to append the errors in `@comment` to the page from the `create.js.erb`

Comment: I were getting errors - Had to change Your code a bit into this:`<% if @comment.errors.empty? %>
  $(".comments").html("<%= escape_javascript(render @guide.comments) %>");
  $('#comment_body').val('');
<% else %>
  $("#notice").html("Error! Comment not posted.");
<% end %>`
Thanks for help - It worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Well I managed to clear the textarea by simply adding:

```
$(".comments").html("<%= escape_javascript(render @guide.comments) %>");
$('#comment_body').val('');
```

Now there is only second problem left - how to display errors, flash[messages] etc via ajax? I think It is worth mentioning I have partial for error messages (_error_messages.html.erb):

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```